# Blogger: Show widgets only in posts from specific authors

Tags: javascript, templates, blogger

I try to show specific widgets in posts from specific authors (I have a multi-authors blog). 
E.g. Widget 1 for author 1, widget 2 for author 2 e.t.c.

Or specific content in a widget for specific authors (e.g. widget 1: Content A for Author 1, Widget 1: Content B for Author 2 etc.)

In fact, I try to use different ads code for every author in specific widgets.

When I put javascript with ads code below the body of an article (inside the same widget with the content of a post) everything is ok. I use the `<b:if cond='data:post.author == bla bla bla`  statement and it works perfectly.

But when I try to do the same thing in another widget of the template (I use the same statement `<b:if cond='data:post.author == bla bla bla` then the system does not recognize the author of the post and the if statement is never true so I have no content in the widget.

Answer (score 0):

`data:post.author` belongs to blog posts so you can't use it outside Blog widget `type='Blog'`.

You can set Javascript variable for each author inside Blog widget and use it with if statement where you want.

**Example:**

```
<b:if cond='data:post.author == "someone"'>
    <script>
        var author = "someone";
    </script>
</b:if>

..................
............
.......

<script>
    if (author === "someone") {}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The widget with id "Blog1" cannot contain element: "b:if". A widget can only contain b:includable elements

So you can't use "b:if" inside Blog widget
The solution:

```
<b:if cond='data:post.author == "someone"'> 
    <style type='text/css'> 
        #grid2wrap .container .grid2wrap:before { background: #950e0e;} 
    </style> 
</b:if>
```